# Where to get SharePoint.StackExchange.com shirts?

Tags: discussion

I was at the SharePoint Conference 2011 and saw someone wearing one.  Are these available for sale somewhere or was this some sort of custom deal?

Comment: You should have come up to us and said "hello" ;-)

Comment: I did say, "Nice Shirt" to someone, but I'm not sure if they heard me.  Smaller guy with blondish hair if I remember correctly.  I'll have to track you down next year if I make it out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the StackExchange shirts are available for sale, but so far SPSE havent been available in the Stackoverflow stores.

The ones people are wearing are the ones I gave away at SharePoint Conference in Anaheim and SPSUK last week.

Comment: Was there a SPSE booth at the conference?

Comment: SPSE sponsored t-shirts and stickers that I gave away at those two conferences